# ACPI BIOS error (bug) - Ubuntu does not boot anymore

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, bios, acpi

I dual booted my laptop (HP Zbook studio G5) to be able to use Linux alongside Windows. Went completely fine for 3/4 weeks or so, and suddenly today I got hit with this, and Ubuntu won't boot anymore. It stays stuck on the error screen linked below. I believe I also got some messages, before booting, when it worked, but I did not pay attention to them, as I thought it's nothing but simple warnings, as everything worked fine.

I managed to take care of the first error by enabling SGX in bios, but the ACPI BIOS errors remain. Searching for solutions, many people suggested adding a parameter to the kernel : *acpi=off* or *acpi=strict*. Tried this and still couldn't get past this stage, with Ubuntu still not booting and showing these ACPI errors. I also tried to update my bios, but I have the latest version, and I am not allowed to downgrade it.

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

I was low on space on one disk, having like 700mb left, could that have been an issue? I do not see how it is related, but I'm trying to think of what could have caused this.

Error image, 1st line is now solved, everything below is still showing:

[image]

Comment: General comment: when a line is displayed during boot it is NOT a problem that halts booting. It is the one that is not shown next that is the cause. ACPI errors are non-fatal and the system will continue. It is a mismatch between your BIOS and the kernel; those errors used to be ignored by the kernel but nowadays are echoed to the display.  Can you at this point already use control-alt-f1 to get a login prompt?

Comment: "Malformed MSFT vendor" is a BT device that does not follow the specifications. It is also benign. Have you done anything related to the video card driver?? I would expect that one to be a show-stopper if anything went wrong with that.

Comment: Not enough disk space Ubuntu wont boot.

Comment: @Rinzwind I will try using control-alt-f1 to see if I can get to login. Also, in regards to malformed MSFT vendor, Im not sure what that is. Its possible I have update my graphics driver, would that be the cause?

Comment: @David and how could I solve that without being able to boot Ubuntu? I am quite a rookie when it comes to this, as I just experienced Linux for a few weeks, and I allocated 2 disk spaces of 16gb, where one of them got full and the other remained quite empty. I wasnt aware of how I could move stuff from one to the other, so it got to the point it warned me about having only 700Mb or so space left in one drive.

Comment: Use the live media to boot.

Comment: I managed to boot in and it was indeed the space that caused the problem, thank you!

Comment: @CorladeDenis cool. make it an answer and explain how you solved it. Then you can upvote and accept it; that way the system will not show it in the queue.